# How can I make a one-shot sshd process?

Tags: sshd, netcat

I'm trying to find some invocation of `sshd` (OpenSSH on Ubuntu) that accepts only one connection, and then terminates the `sshd` process when that one connection closes.

I see nothing in the `sshd` docs that would indicate that this is intrinsically possible, so I was thinking that it might be possible to rig up `nc` as a one-shot proxy, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem where the `sshd` process continues running after the connection has closed.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds awfully [XY-ish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Running `sshd` on an instance in a cluster and connecting to it. On this cluster job/instance lifecycle is tied to the lifetime of the launched process. I want to spawn the instance, connect to it once, and then have it automatically die when the client disconnects. I guess the "only one connection" thing isn't strictly required, but, the bottom line is that the `sshd` process needs to die when the last client connection goes away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `sshd` in debug mode makes it accept only one connection and then quit, as stated in manual page for `sshd`:

> **-d**
>
> Debug mode.  The server sends verbose debug output to standard error, and does not put itself in the background.  The server also will not fork and will only process one connection.  This option is only intended for debugging for the server.  Multiple -d options increase the debugging level.  Maximum is 3.

This is typical use case for debugging, if you run the server like this:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

Comment: Wow. I had tried that, but it appeared to keep living, so I moved on. Must have been some other problem, because it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use `pam` for that. In your `/etc/pam.d` directory find a file related to SSH (in my case, it's called `sshd` on a Ubuntu Trusty machine). Edit it and add a line like this:

```
session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /opt/myscript.sh
```

That will make the script be called on any login and logout. As you only wish to do an action on logout, the content of the script could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "close_session" ]; then
  /etc/init.d/sshd stop
fi
```